# is it safe to install Debian 6 on a dedicated server? (LAMP)

Tags: linux, debian, web-server, lamp

Is it safe to install Debian 6 on a dedicated server? (LAMP)

My hosting company gives the choice to install it ( Debian 6, 64-bit "squeeze" ALPHA )
They said it's wrote ALPHA because it's not a stable distro so far.

At this point I don't know if it's a good choice or not.

What do you suggest?

Comment: I guess your hosting company haven't updated their notice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Debian 6 (Squeeze) is the new "stable" release, so it's highly recommended for servers.

Comment: Look here: http://www.ovh.co.uk/items/distributions/debian.xml they keep saying debian 6 is alpha.. doh

Comment: If your hoster is incapable of supporting the current stable release, find a new hoster.

Comment: Debian 6 only came out two days ago, any sensible hosting provider is not going to start telling everyone to adopt it. That doesn't mean it shouldn't be used (I trust Debian a lot), just that it's not an indicator of a bad provider.

Comment: i contacted the support. They said the label ALPHA is just an internal label because debian 6 is out only few days ago. They will remove it as soon as the first big wave of bugfixes will be realeased. Anyway i just bought a server with squeeze :D

Comment: Debian isn't like Ubuntu or the others where you have to wait for a shakeout before it's safe to run.  When they promote something to "stable", it's because it's ready to run your enterprise.